# I am trying to implement blog app with Django.I created registration form with profile pic upload.But its not submitting data?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to implement blog app with Django. I created registration form with profile pic upload. However after I enter data and choose image, and click on submit its not submitting data. It returns same registration page.Instead of submitting data.

```
  #models.py
  class Profile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='pics')

  #views.py
  def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
     form = Register(request.POST,request.FILES)
     if form.is_valid():
        profile = Profile()
        email = form.cleaned_data['Email']
        User_name=form.cleaned_data['Username']
        Password=form.cleaned_data['Password']
        Confirm_Password=form.cleaned_data['Confirm_Password']
        firstname=form.cleaned_data['Firstname']
        user=User.objects.create_user(username=User_name,
                      password=Password,email=email,first_name=firstname)
        user.save();
        profile.image = form.cleaned_data["Image"]
        profile.save();
        return redirect('/')
    else:
     form = Register()
    return render(request,'register.html',{'form': form})

    #forms.py
    class Register(forms.Form):
        Email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs= 
                                               {"class":"inputvalues"}))
        Username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs= 
                                               {"class":"inputvalues"}))
        Password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs= 
                                               ({"class":"inputvalues"})))
        Firstname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs= 
                                  {"class":"inputvalues"}),max_length=30)
        Lastname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs= 
                                  {"class":"inputvalues"}),max_length=40)
        Confirm_Password = forms.CharField
             (widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=({"class":"inputvalues"})))
        Image = forms.ImageField()

    def clean_Email(self):
      if validate_email(self.cleaned_data['Email']):
        raise forms.ValidationError("Email is not in correct format!")
      elif User.objects.filter(email = self.cleaned_data['Email'])
                                                       .exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("Email aready exist!")
      return self.cleaned_data['Email']
    def clean_Username(self):
      if User.objects.filter(username = 
                        self.cleaned_data['Username']).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("Username already exist!")
      return self.cleaned_data['Username']
    def clean_Confirm_Password(self):
      pas=self.cleaned_data['Password']
      cpas = self.cleaned_data['Confirm_Password']
      if pas != cpas:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Password and Confirm Password are not 
                                                     matching!")
      else:
        if len(pas) < 8:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Password should have atleast 8 
                                                         character")
        if pas.isdigit():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Password should not all numeric")

  <!-------register.html>
  {% extends 'layout.html' %}
  {% block content %}
    <div class="box">
        <h2>
            <center>Register</center>
        </h2><br>
        <form action='register' method='POST'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div>
                <label class='labe'>Image:</label>
                {{ form.Image }}
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class='labe'>First name:</label>
                {{ form.Firstname }}
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class='labe'>Last name:</label>
                {{ form.Lastname }}
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class='labe'>Email:</label>
                {{ form.Email }}
                {{ form.Email.errors }}
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class='labe'>Username:</label>
                {{ form.Username }}
                {{ form.Username.errors }}
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class='labe'>Password:</label>
                {{ form.Password }}

            </div>
            <div>
                <label class='labe'>Confirm Password:</label>
                {{ form.Confirm_Password }}
                {{ form.Confirm_Password.errors }}
            </div>
            <input type="Submit" id="lg"/><br>
            <center><a href="login" >Already have an account.Login here. 
                                             </a></center>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div>
        {% for message in messages%}
            <h1>{{message}}</h1>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
  {% endblock %}
```

It returns same registration page.Instead of submitting data.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what's going on because your indentation is not consistent. It appears though that the form you're submitting isn't valid. I see you're displaying the errors for most individual fields - but there could be some [non_field_errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.non_field_errors) which you are not displaying. That seems the most likely scenario here, otherwise make sure that you don't have CSS which is hiding the errors. You can always try to print the errors to the terminal as a last resort.

Comment: But is my views.py code correct?

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems with it

Answer (score 0):

Your form needs to be `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">`

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST

Comment: relation "blog_profile" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "blog_profile" ("user_id", "image") VALUES (NULL... after adding  enctype="multipart/form-data" the following error occurs

Comment: That's a different issue now. Have you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`? You need them to get your model into the database. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/